# Property 'transition' does not exist on type 'Selection<BaseType, {}, null, undefined>'

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, transition

I want to use d3js in angular2, but when I want to add transition when element change it occur an error:
`Property 'transition' does not exist on type 'Selection<BaseType, {}, null, undefined>'`
I use angular-cli to generate project, and the version of angular is 4.0.0, and d3js is 4.8.0

Here is my `typings.d.ts`:

```
declare module 'd3' {
export * from 'd3-array';
export * from 'd3-axis';
export * from 'd3-brush';
export * from 'd3-chord';
export * from 'd3-collection';
export * from 'd3-color';
export * from 'd3-dispatch';
export * from 'd3-drag';
export * from 'd3-dsv';
export * from 'd3-ease';
export * from 'd3-force';
export * from 'd3-format';
export * from 'd3-geo';
export * from 'd3-hierarchy';
export * from 'd3-interpolate';
export * from 'd3-path';
export * from 'd3-polygon';
export * from 'd3-quadtree';
export * from 'd3-queue';
export * from 'd3-random';
export * from 'd3-request';
export * from 'd3-scale';
export * from 'd3-selection';
export * from 'd3-shape';
export * from 'd3-time';
export * from 'd3-time-format';
export * from 'd3-timer';
export * from 'd3-transition';
export * from 'd3-voronoi';
export * from 'd3-zoom';
```

}

Here is my app.component.ts

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
......
d3.select(this).select("path").transition().attr("d", function(d) {
            console.log(d);
            return arc2(<any>d);
        })
```

If I remove `transition()` it performs good.

How to solve it? Thanks

Comment: can you post on jsfiddle?

Comment: @TheBiro here is the github repo https://github.com/justforuse/angular2-d3-transition-issue, I don't know how to generate angular4 demo in jsfiddle, sorry

Comment: I tried npm uninstall --save-dev @types/d3, and restart project, everything works well and no error occured, So is that says @types/d3 has bug?

Comment: well. I found the problem.. I use [cnpm](https://github.com/cnpm/cnpm) not npm to install the packages

Comment: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/16176

Answer (score 5):

I have fixed my code by:

```
import { select as d3Select } from 'd3-selection';
import { transition as d3Transition } from 'd3-transition';
d3Select.prototype.transition = d3Transition;
```

and then use d3Select in your code insted of select

you can follow:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/16176

Comment: Although this might fix the problem it shouldn't be necessary. Has anyone figured out why this is still a problem?